# Is concurrent user of a wireless AP channel bandwith dependence

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, bandwidth

I have been told that a wireless AP, 2.4GHz radio can support concurrent user of 50 users maximum.

The figure is based on test results from  300Mbps of bitrate, at 40MHz of channel bandwidth.

I wonder if the concurrent user would go higher than 50 if I use 20MHz of channel bandwidth instead?

Comment: I dont want to offend your adviser who told you this number, but he/she is wrong. There're too many factors that can change this number either up or down significantly. Without site survey , knowing site's network tasks and requirements, clients devices, radio network topology it just wrong calculation. As about 20 vs 40 - it hard to say without site survey, if there a bunch of WiFi APs that aren't under you control then 20 would be more reliable since it would less interfering with others. The same applied to your clients, some of devices still dont know abt 40Mhz but others will took all

Answer (score 0):

All else being equal, cutting your bandwidth in half is going to cut your number of supported concurrent users by at least half.

A single 802.11 AP radio using a single BSSID has a hard protocol limitation of 2007 concurrent STAs (client devices). Any time someone talks about a limit smaller than that, they're either talking about limitations in the design of the hardware or software of a specific implementation (e.g. a specific brand & model of 802.11 AP), or they have a certain minimum acceptable service level in mind (e.g. they want to make sure everyone gets at least, say, 1Mbps throughput, with less than 20ms latency and less than 0.01% packet loss).

So if you have a given setup that meets your minimum service level for 50 clients when using 40MHz channel bandwidth, cutting that channel bandwidth in half will ensure that no more than 25 clients can get your minimum service level (probably less than 25, and increased contention for the medium will cause a decrease in efficiency; clients will spend more time fighting for airtime and less time successfully transmitting and receiving).